# Command Prompt not displaying the Current Directory before prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

Whenever I run command prompt, it works fine but is not showing the current directory before the prompt(blinking).How can this be solved?[image]

Comment: what does `echo %prompt% say?

Comment: This message is displayed :'$p$G'

Comment: hmm - that's what it's supoposed to be...

Comment: No. It remains the same.

Comment: The answer by Vishal Saini solved it.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try superuser.com.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.) Open up registry editor by typing "regedit" [without the quotes] in the search box, and then clicking on the link up top.

2.) Navigate to the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Command Processor and search for the string "Autorun" in the left window. If that string is not existing yet, create it. Double-click it afterwards and add the new directory path in the following way: CD /d C:\

3.) If you would like the command prompt to open in the system32 folder, use this string instead:
CD /d C:\windows\system32

It solved mine!

Comment: Setting `autorun` will break batch files.

Comment: it's just adding a string! 
No harm done!

Comment: Um, no, you're adding `CD /d C:\` which changes the starting directory. [This breaks batch files and other command lines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/21/6447771.aspx).

Comment: It solved the guy's problem. :p

Comment: It solved the problem and created another problem.